# IOS - idevicesyslog command line tool - How to add milli seconds to the logs?

Tags: ios, iphone, logging

Connected iPhone to the Mac laptop and trying to check the iPhone logs.

iOS idevicesyslog command line tool is printing the log time stamps in sec. **But how to add milliseconds to log time stamp?**

**Example log line**

```
Apr 30 22:39:00 kernel(AppleARMPlatform)[0] <Notice>: Quota update for stream kGPU_Reads. PrevSize: 0x800000 newSize: 0x0 totalAssignedCache: 0x7ed80
```

**idevicesyslog tool**

```
Usage: **idevicesyslog** [OPTIONS]

Relay syslog of a connected device.

OPTIONS:
  -u, --udid UDID  target specific device by UDID
  -n, --network    connect to network device
  -x, --exit       exit when device disconnects
  -h, --help       prints usage information
  -d, --debug      enable communication debugging
  -v, --version    prints version information
 --no-colors       disable colored output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ts command to add time stamp

```
idevicesyslog | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]'
```